# Bug, padding go overflow in inline-flex+block+flex+block container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I found strange case. when I use html like that :

```html
<div class="card" style="display:inline-flex; overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="display: block; width:10em; height: 5em;">
    <div style="display:flex;">
      <!-- here -->
      <div style="padding-bottom: 10em;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `div padding-bottom:10em` push out others `div.card` blow the `div.card` like the padding is some invisible part of the `div.card`

When I change the internal `flex div` to `block div` the bug disapear

It look like the internal flex as it own layout that breach out from the `blok` and the outer `inline-flex`

How I prevent that, and make the div with the padding cut out like normal content into overflow hidden element.

It can be I found new bug in chrome flex model ?

Live example :
https://uvzoo.csb.app/
Codesendbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-engelbart-uvzoo

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block; width:30em; height: 40em; padding: 1em;">
  <!--  block card -->
  <div style="display:inline-flex; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="display: block; width:10em; height: 5em;">
      <div style="display:flex;">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 10em;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end block card -->
  <!--  block card -->
  <div style="display:inline-flex; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="display: block; width:10em; height: 5em;">
      <div style="display:flex;">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 10em;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end block card -->
  <!--  block card -->
  <div style="display:inline-flex; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="display: block; width:10em; height: 5em;">
      <div style="display:flex;">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 10em;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end block card -->
  <!--  block card -->
  <div style="display:inline-flex; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="display: block; width:10em; height: 5em;">
      <div style="display:flex;">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 10em;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end block card -->
  <!--  block card -->
  <div style="display:inline-flex; overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="display: block; width:10em; height: 5em;">
      <div style="display:flex;">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 10em;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end block card -->
</div>
```

Comment: it happen also on Firefox

Comment: The `<div style="padding-bottom: 10em;"></div>` is a flexbox child container that needs to be allowed to grow to full parent width by adding `flex-grow: 1`. Add `body>div>div>div>div>div { flex-grow: 1 }` to your sandbox CSS

Comment: ok thanks. I add that , but it not change the case . just make the inner dive to expand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align:top` fixes the issue. I don't know exactly why but it seems there is a complex calculation that is affecting the baseline calculation of each box making it outside and far from the bottom. Since `baseline` is the default alignment, you are getting this *strange* result

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align:top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box>div {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
}

.box>div>div {
  display: flex;
}

.box>div>div>div {
  padding-bottom: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block; width:30em; height: 40em; padding: 1em;">
  <!--  block card -->
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If we add some text we can notice this:

```css
div {
  outline: 1px solid pink;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box>div {
  display: block;
  width: 10em;
  height: 5em;
}

.box>div>div {
  display: flex;
}

.box>div>div>div {
  padding-bottom: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: block; padding: 1em;">
  <!--  block card -->
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> some text here 
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> some text here 
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe has something to do with the inline-flex container. overflow don't work on inline elements but it's inline-flex so it kind of works but kind of not. Weird for sure, good workaround

Comment: @Huangism overflow does work on inline-flex or inline-block element, it doesn't work on only *inline* element. I am pretty sure it's due to all the nesting (flexbox and non-flexbox). Will update if I find the accurate reason

Comment: I was playing with your code and it seems if you put `align-items: baseline` instead of `vertical-align: top` it actually extends the box. Just an observation, doesn't solve this issue lol

Comment: @Huangism intresting, align-items should align the content *inside* so it's strange to see the parent box having its height changed

Comment: Well they also say vertical align has no effect on flex but it does in this case

Comment: @Huangism you are confusing about the model inside and outside. Vertical-align in this case is applied to an inline-* element (flexbox play no role here). Flexbox is the layout *inside* the element and there vertical-align will do nothing. From the outside the item is an inline-level element and behave exactly like inline-block, inline-grid, etc ... align-items is a applied to a flexbox container (*-flex) and will affect the element inside that are flex items

Comment: Maybe the `align-items:baseline` make the `inline-flex` aware to all it content (include the padding) and expend to reflect this. because `inline-*` expend to the size of it content